# Adding Sort to Group Members

Tags: silverstripe

I have a Page that displays a list of Members in a group, but I need to change the sort of the group members. I though the esiest way would be to add a relation editor to the pagetype with the sort order added via a Data Extension

Here is my extension on Group

```
class MyGroup extends DataExtension {
    static $many_many_extraFields = array(
        'Members' => array(
            'SortOrder' => "Int"
        )
    );
}
```

On the Page I have the following:

```
if($this->GroupID != 0 && Permission::check("APPLY_ROLES")) {
    $group = Group::get()->byID($this->GroupID);
    $fields->addFieldsToTab("Root.Members", array(
         GridField::create(
            "Members",
            "Members",
            $group->DirectMembers(),
            GridFieldConfig_RelationEditor::create()->addComponents(
                new GridFieldSortableRows('SortOrder')
            )
        )
    ));
}
```

When I try to sort the Members I get an error

```
Uncaught SS_DatabaseException: Couldn't run query:
UPDATE "" SET "SortOrder" = 1 WHERE "" = 12 AND "" = 18
```

I'm not sure why GridField isn't getting the Columns

Answer (score 0):

You can define the sort order on the list you use for the gridfield

```
$group->DirectMembers()->sort('Whatever')
```

If you want to sort them manually, have a look at https://github.com/silverstripe-australia/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions or https://github.com/UndefinedOffset/SortableGridField.

Both modules give you the possibility to sort the entries with drag and drop.

Comment: I have both plugins instaled. The problem is that the Gridfield won't write the sort, It's missing the Table and Columns in the Query. If I manually update the table the sort order works just fine.

Comment: hmm, ok than I'll try to replicate that behavior later that day, perhaps I find something out.